# Ошибка импортирования tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-import

Я собирал python3.9 из оффицальных исходников, у меня работает все, кроме tkinter.
P.S. У меня стоит Ubuntu 16.04 и оффицально python3.9 На этом дистрибутиве в apt не входит.
Пробовал устанавливать через ppa:deadsnakes, но этот репозиторий ничего мне не даёт (ничего в apt не добавляет).
Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 188, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 147, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 111, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

Что мне нужно добавить при сборке python3.9 чтобы tkinter заработал?

Comment: Вот тут много вариантов, что с такой ошибкой можно попробовать: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459444/tkinter-python-may-not-be-configured-for-tk

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте установить библиотеку через pip:

```
pip install python3-tk
```

Или

```
pip install tk
```

Comment: tkinter не устанавливается через pip, только через системный пакетный менеджер, типа `apt install python3-tk`

Comment: Нет, и нет, на pypi.org нет таких пакетов, вообще нет пакета tkinter, поэтому через pip установить не получится, ни как python3-tk, ни tk, ни tkinter.

Comment: Более того, pip install tk установит не tkinter, а "TensorKit is a deep learning helper between Python and C++."

Comment: Я же сказал что в Ubuntu 16.04 python3.9 не поддерживается через apt

Comment: Что нужно добавить в билд чтобы установить все библиотеки (я собирал python не через apt)

Comment: Очень странно, множество сайтов указывают на обратное при запросе «Install Tkinter 16.04»

Comment: @MineFine тогда без понятия. В крайнем случае можно попробовать из исходников собрать, вот исходник _tkinter: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_tkinter.c Правда еще нужны будут tcl файлы к нему вроде бы.

Comment: @insolor спасибо, попробую